# Node - check existence of command in path

Tags: node.js, path, command

I have a unique problem where I need to use Node to iterate over several Unix-style commands and see if they exist in the `path` of a Windows installation.

For instance, Windows doesn't support `ls` natively. However, supposing someone installed `git` and checked to include Unix commands, it would.

I need to know whether or not `ls` and other commands are in the system `path`.

Right now, I'm using `child_process` to run `help` on each command. I then check the response of running it. This is messy and dangerous. I don't want to run 30 arbitrary commands from Node:

```
var spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;
var out = spawnSync('ls', ['/?'], {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

How else can I check for the existence of these commands?

Comment: There's actually [middleware](https://github.com/mathisonian/command-exists) for that ?

Comment: That's sloppy, lazy middleware. It just does a `var child = exec('which ' + commandName);`. The command `which` doesn't exist on Windows. I already looked for a cross-platform shell command to determine process existence, and I can't find one.

Comment: Not sure if there's something magical that works in everything, you'd probably be better of if you know wether or not you're working with dos or bash etc.

Comment: FYI, both Windows and Linux have `where`, with the same arguments

Comment: @adeneo hmm - just checked my Ubuntu installation and it didn't have it by default. Perhaps some do, but this is part of a Node installer package that has to work on 99.99999% of all OSes.

Comment: @adeneo I can tell which I am working with: `require('os').platform().indexOf('win') > -1` works in Node.

Comment: Oops, Windows has `where`, Ubuntu would have `whereis`, same thing, different name. Again, nothing works everywhere

Comment: Hmm. I think we're onto something. Do you know if `whereis` is stable across all Linux installations?

Comment: Should be, it's been around forever, and is part of the core as far as I know

Comment: Nice. You want to make that an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: Just note that it doesn't really check commands, but executables, for instance `where dir` doesn't work, but `where cmd` does work, as the latter is an executable (cmd.exe) that can be called globally in windows etc. If someone added `ls` to windows, they surely added an executable file, so it should in theory work ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking - I had noticed that as well. Basically, the thing I'm doing [installs Linux commands on Windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash), so there would have to be an executable, I think. Right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `whereis` in Linux, and `where` in Windows, to see if the executable can be found

```
var isWin = require('os').platform().indexOf('win') > -1;

var where = isWin ? 'where' : 'whereis';

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var out = spawn(where + ' ls', ['/?'], {encoding: 'utf8'});

out.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('exit code : ' + code);
});
```

Comment: `whereis` on Mac OS doesn't seem to locate commands in `/usr/local/bin` (which is in my `PATH` env var). But `which` does.

Comment: Edited answer to include Mac OS.

Comment: I get an error `Error: spawn where ls ENOENT` on macos.

Comment: @loretoparisi - `ENOENT` means no such file or directory, and as it says in the comment above, `whereis` doesn't locate commands on MacOS, you'll need to include `which` somehow

Comment: `where` is not worked in Windows PowerShell, use `where.exe` instead, or `gcm` (alias of `Get-Command`)

Answer (score 20):

Personally I have found that the [command-exists module](https://github.com/mathisonian/command-exists) on npm works great.

### Installation

```
npm install command-exists
```

### Usage

- async

  ```
  var commandExists = require('command-exists');

  commandExists('ls', function(err, commandExists) {

      if(commandExists) {
          // proceed confidently knowing this command is available
      }

  });
  ```
- promise

  ```
  var commandExists = require('command-exists');

  // invoked without a callback, it returns a promise
  commandExists('ls')
  .then(function(command){
      // proceed
  }).catch(function(){
      // command doesn't exist
  });
  ```
- sync

  ```
  var commandExistsSync = require('command-exists').sync;
  // returns true/false; doesn't throw
  if (commandExistsSync('ls')) {
      // proceed
  } else {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: For **Windows** commands, is there a need to add the `.exe` suffix? Like so: `commandExists('curl.exe', function(err, commandExists) {...}` ?

Comment: This also returns true if you pass in an executable that is in the directory in which you are calling this code. Not too sure if that should happen.

e.g.  ```node ~/dev/that-code.js ./script``` should return false because it's not on the PATH. while ```node ~/dev/that-code.js npm``` should return true because npm is on PATH.

Answer (score 5):

**DON'T** use `child_process` just for that, neither packages which use `child_process` internally. [As Matt already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953266/1368868), the most straightforward way is just checking under your Path.

Here is a NPM [`lookpath`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lookpath) package which scans your `$PATH` or `$Path`.

```
const { lookpath } = require('lookpath');

const p = await lookpath('bash');
// "/bin/bash"
```

This is a Node.js port of [`exec.LookPath`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/lp_unix.go?s=928:970#L2) from Go.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

**2021-10-13**

I looked at these Node packages and listed by preference and why:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/which - small footprint with one dependency that looks through paths and is OS agnostic.
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-which - adds NPM path to [which’s](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which) lookup.
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lookpath - similar to [which](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which) but one has to explicitly state the extension.
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-exists - uses child processes if fs.access return is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not check in your Path directories,  and see if the ls command file exists.

If the files doesn't exist in the directories,  then it's not in path.

Comment: I suppose I could iterate over all paths, but that seems a bit inefficient. Would like for there to be a better solution, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @dthree Compared to spawning child processes, walking through PATH is more efficient. I implemented a NPM to do that https://www.npmjs.com/package/lookpath See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56321089/1368868 for more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions for different shells are provided here:

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081

e.g. for bash:

```
# Bash
if hash qwerty 2>/dev/null; then
  echo qwerty exists
else
  echo qwerty does not exist
fi
```

Comment: Also cross-ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-do-i-test-to-see-if-an-application-exists-in-path